# My localhost is accessible form other devices. How to fix?

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I have an localhost on my mac and it is accessible from other devices by typing the IP address of the mac, I don't want that it is accessible from others, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Use a firewall obviously

Comment: already have a firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to change the Apache directive value from:

```
Listen  80
```

to:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

in your httpd.conf file, then restart the server :)

Comment: Listen 0.0.0.0:80 will make it accesible to all devices on the router. i do not want this Listen 0.0.0.0:80 is like listen 80 i want that it is only accessible my one device the primary

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're describing a situation in which your Mac's installation is accessible to other devices on your network via it's internal IP address. If instead you meant to describe a situation involving the Mac's external IP, configure a firewall on your network.

Since this has the Apache tag, I'll assume you're using an apache webserver. Please refer to Apache's access control documentation I've linked below. If you mean to allow access through localhost only you'd have in your .htaccess file

```
 Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Comment: Thanks this helped now it says when i type it on other devices : Forbiddenyou dont have permission :D ! but i want it to make the localhost unreachable like when i type my macs ip i want it to load and says cannot connect